# jQuery datepicker not working after call Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, datepicker

jQuery datepicker does not work after calling Ajax

I'm using jQuery datepicker to get posts from database(datewise). I tried this code
`

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
     $(function() { $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" }).val() }); 
     </script> 
     Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" size="30"/>
```

`
It's working fine.

Now I call ajax like this, it's not showing calender.not working also.Is it correct? I need your help
`

```
$(function() {
     var currentTime = new Date();
     var day = currentTime.getDate();
     var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
     var year = currentTime.getFullYear();

     if (day < 10){
     day = "0" + day;
     }

     if (month < 10){
     month = "0" + month;
     }

     var today_date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
     var dataString ='date='+today_date;

     $("#datepicker").datepicker({

     onSelect: function(dateTypeVar, instance) {
     var dateAsObject =   $("#datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"}).val();
     var dataString ='date='+dateAsObject; 
     $.ajax
     ({
              type: "Post",
              url: "<?php echo home_url(); ?>/?datepost",
              data: dataString
              success: function(data)
              {
                  $('#testdiv').html(data);
              }
         });  
   
     }
     });

     });
     </script>
```

`

This is Mysql Query in function.php
`

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['datepost']))
     {
     $date = $_POST['date'];
     $res=mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM  `wp_posts` WHERE DATE_FORMAT(post_date,  '%m/%d/%Y') =  '".$date."' AND post_type = 'post'  ORDER BY post_date DESC
LIMIT 0 , 1");
     $post_id=mysql_fetch_array($res);
     $pid = $post_id['ID'];
     exit();
     }`
```

Comment: Hi friends,Any body is here?

Comment: Do you see any error in console?

Comment: i didn't get any error. if i remove this ajax function. calender is working fine. but i want ajax call, b'coz need to retrive data from database.
     `$.ajax
     ({
              type: "Post",
              url: "<?php echo home_url(); ?>/?datepost",
              data: dataString
              success: function(data)
              {
                  $('#testdiv').html(data);
              }
         });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't added comma after this line `data: dataString` in the ajax request, which is might be breaking your js code.

Try adding a comma.

```
$.ajax ({
    type: "Post",
    url: "<?php echo home_url(); ?>/?datepost",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#testdiv').html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60129/discussion-on-answer-by-s-rupali-jquery-datepicker-not-workinng-after-call-ajax).